# Свойства предмета в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

Создаю виртуальный музей на unity. Когда игрок подходит к экспонату и нажимает на Е, должно появиться подробное описание и камера 360. Но если с камерой все понятно, то как сделать само "окно"?

Comment: "к сожалению на Unity" при таком подходе, я считаю, наилучшее решение для Вас - сменить инструмент

Comment: https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui  Что значит  "к сожалению на Unity" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать это `UI (User Interface)` система. Для `UI` у Unity есть специальные компоненты, которые должны быть расположены на `Canvas (Холсте)`. Грубо говоря, вы можете понаделать кучу элементов, которые будут отображены на канвасе с `WorldSpace` отображением. Поставить вокруг каждого экспоната триггеры и написать скрипт, чтобы в момент `OnTriggerStay()`, если нажата `E`, включался определённый `GameObject`.

Можно лучи пускать по нажатию `E`, что тоже даст примерно такой же результат. Только в экспонат надо будет попасть. Но можно будет сделать круче: автоматически как бы раскрывать табличку, если игрок на неё смотрит. Вот так вот.

Господи, да много как это реализуемо! Хоть тот же `Vector3.Distance()` применяй и отлавливай нажатие на `E`.

В любом случае, вам нужно сделать холст, а чтобы ознакомиться с тем, как устроена система `UI` в `Unity`, вы можете ознакомиться с этими [уроками](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui). И конечно же не забывайте про документацию и приложение усилий!

Comment: А получится ли управляемая камера внутри UI (как по оси вокруг предмета [как её сделать я знаю, а насчёт UI не уверен])

Comment: @Александр UI - это такой же GameObject, который имеет свой Transfrom